# To select data from SQL server based on value stored in shared preferences and keep the data into shared preference too

Tags: java, sql-server, android-studio, session, sharedpreferences

I have a login page that work well with shared preference. After login, I would like to select the 'Name' column from the database (SQL Server) correspond to the **login Id** **and password**. I need the result to get display on my Edittext **(txt_name)** so that I can store the 'Name' into shared preference too for future use.

Here I attach my code :

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ConnectionClass connectionClass;
    EditText edtuserid,edtpass,txt_name;
    Button btnlogin;
    ProgressBar pbbar;

    UserSessionManager session;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        session = new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
        edtuserid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtuserid);
        edtpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpass);
        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        pbbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
        pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DoLogin doLogin = new DoLogin();
                doLogin.execute("");

            }
        });

    }

    public class DoLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        String z = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;


        String userid = edtuserid.getText().toString();
        String password = edtpass.getText().toString();
        String name;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
            pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,r,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User Login Status: " + session.isUserLoggedIn(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is my Toast message!" + ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            if(isSuccess) {

//                if(r != null)
//                    txt_name.setText(Html.fromHtml(r));
//                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddProducts.class);
//                startActivity(i);
//                finish();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {



            if(userid.trim().equals("")|| password.trim().equals(""))
                z = "Please enter User Id and Password";
            else
            {
                try {
                    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                    if (con == null) {
                        z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                    } else {
                        String query = "select * from Employee where Id='" + userid + "' and Password='" + password + "'";
                        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
//                        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));

                        int count=0;

                        if(rs.next())
                        {
                            count++;

                            Statement s=con.createStatement();
                            ResultSet rst=s.executeQuery("select * from Employee where Id='" + userid + "' and Password='" + password + "'");
                            while(rst.next()){

                            }

//                            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                            session.createUserLoginSession("'" + userid +"'",
                                    "'" + password +"'");


                            z = "Login successfull";
                            isSuccess=true;


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            z = "Invalid Credentials";
                            isSuccess = false;
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    isSuccess = false;
                    z = "Exceptions";
                }
            }
            return z;

        }

    }}
```

I'm new in android development, please notify me if I missed something or you have any solution to this.

Comment: Stop injecting values! Parametrise your queries. Your code also **heavily** implies you're storing plain text passwords in your database. Never do this. Passwords should be salted and hashed and only the hashed values should be passed to the RDBMS.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Sorry sir, but as a beginner, I just learn to create login using shared preferences by this way and it work well. Unfortunately, I can't retrieve the user's 'Name' and display it in my Edittext. I would be appreciate if you can show me some solution for this @Larnu